# How to get Attentions Part from the output of a Bert model?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, word-embedding

##### I am using `Bert-Model` for  Query Expansion and I am trying to extract the keywords from the Document I have

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
sentence="This is a sentence"
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence)
print(tokens,"-tokens")
input_ids = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokens)
input_ids = torch.tensor(\[input_ids\])
print(input_ids)
with torch.no_grad():
output = model(input_ids)
attention_scores = output.attentions
print(attention_scores)   #this prints None
```

this is my code I am using a Simple Sentence and trying to extract keywords from it In order to Do that I need attention of the output part of `Bert-Model`

I tried with Different tokenizer methods(tokenize,encode,encode_plus) to tokenize and tried with
different bert variants (bert-large-uncased)

I want to extract the attention Part form the model output but I am not able to do that

I get None in that place I am not able to get any value in the attention part of  the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't really extract keywords from the code you provided. Your `output` has no attribute called `attentions`, that's why `output.attentions` is returning `None`, hence the error you're facing.

I benchmarked some transformer models for keyword extraction last year for my university project. I will provide you with a solution from there. This script will return you the extracted keywords with their score as a dictionary.

##### Solution

- Install the dependencies

```
pip install nltk
pip install spacy
pip install torch
pip install transformers
```

- Necessary imports

```
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import nltk
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('wordnet')
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

- Utility functions

```
def pre_process(text):
    # lowercase
    text=text.lower()
    #remove tags
    text=re.sub("&lt;/?.*?&gt;"," &lt;&gt; ",text)
    # remove special characters and digits
    text=re.sub("(\\d|\\W)+"," ",text)
    ##Convert to list from string
    text = text.split()
    # remove stopwords
    text = [word for word in text if word not in stop_words]
    # remove words less than three letters
    text = [word for word in text if len(word) >= 3]
    #lemmatize
    lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
    text = [lmtzr.lemmatize(word) for word in text]
    return ' '.join(text)

def get_candidates(text):
    # group of words
    n_gram_range = (1, 1)

    # Extract candidate words/phrases
    count = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=n_gram_range, stop_words="english").fit([text])
    all_candidates = count.get_feature_names_out()
    
    doc = nlp(text)
    noun_phrases = set(chunk.text.strip() for chunk in doc.noun_chunks)

    # Only pass the Noun/Adjective keywords for extraction
    noun_adj = set()
    for token in doc:
        if token.pos_ == "NOUN":
            noun_adj.add(token.text)
        if token.pos_ == "ADJ":
            noun_adj.add(token.text)

    all_words = noun_adj.union(noun_phrases)
    candidates = list(filter(lambda candidate: candidate in all_words, all_candidates))
    return candidates
```

- Keyword Extraction Method

```
# The keyword extraction method
def keyword_extract(string, model_name):

    # Obtaining candidate keywords and document representations
    model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

    text=pre_process(string)
    candidates=get_candidates(text)
    candidate_tokens = tokenizer(candidates, padding=True, return_tensors="pt")
    candidate_embeddings = model(**candidate_tokens)["pooler_output"]

    # Determination of keywords:
    text_tokens = tokenizer([text], padding=True, return_tensors="pt", truncation=True, max_length=512)
    text_embedding = model(**text_tokens)["pooler_output"]

    candidate_embeddings = candidate_embeddings.detach().numpy()
    text_embedding = text_embedding.detach().numpy()

    distances = cosine_similarity(text_embedding, candidate_embeddings)
    keywords = {i:j for i,j in zip(candidates, distances[0])}

    # sort based on attention score and return the dictionary
    return dict(sorted(keywords.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))

# put the model name here
model_name = "bert-base-uncased"

my_sentence = "Hello there! This is an example sentence and this is the code that I'm using to extract keywords from a sentence"

keywords = keyword_extract(my_sentence, model_name)
print(keywords)
```

##### Output

Output returned the keywords sorted according to their score

```
{'keywords': 0.97554314, 'example': 0.94142365, 'extract': 0.885766, 'code': 0.83722556, 'sentence': 0.76782566}
```